# How do you change a .NET bitmap resource?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, bitmap, edit

I need to change a bitmap in the resources of a C# .NET 4.0 program.  I've replaced the underlying .png file with the new image and rebuilt the solution, but it's still is using the OLD IMAGE!

I've spent hours on this!  There's usually a Microsoft gimmick to get "obvious" things to work.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try cleaning the solution. Does that help?

Comment: Already did it.  Repeatedly.  Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your debug folder is having the latest .png, may be its not getting there

Comment: Where is the bitmap located? Within a picturebox?

Comment: Delete it and re-add it? I remember having the same problem a long time ago but not how I solved it :-/

Comment: The bitmap is for a button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in a resource (.resx) file, you need to re-add it manually.

If the resource is something that will change often, using application resources may not be the best solution. Loading the resource from disk would be better if this is the case.

Comment: The changed bitmap does appear in Resources.resx, but the old bitmap appears in the application.  The entry in Resources.Designer.cs references the ID in Resources.resx, but...  the wrong image still comes up.

Comment: Maybe you are looking in the wrong .resx. There is usually a Form1.Resources.resx file for Form-specific resources.

Comment: Kendall, you may be right -- I just commented out the Bitmap entry in Resources.Designer.cs, and the old image still showed up in the toolbar.  It's getting it from somewhere else!